# Rss Implementation with Php

Tags: php, rss

I want to put RSS feeder in my web site. I have created rss-feed.xml file and uploaded it to the server. It's working file. But I want to list all the products in this page. So I created a php page. Here I fetch all the data from product table and wrote in to the xml file. But it's not working see the code below.

```
$sql_pdct="SELECT * FROM tbl_category where bit_active =1 and int_category_id IN ( SELECT int_category_id FROM tbl_product WHERE bit_active =1 )";

    $qry_pdct=mysql_query($sql_pdct);

    If (mysql_num_rows ($qry_pdct)>0){

            While ($row = mysql_fetch_array ($qry_pdct)){
                $con=$row['str_category']; 
                $xml_content .= "<item>\r\n";
                $xml_content .= "<title>".$con."</title>\r\n";
                $xml_content .= "<description><![CDATA[ All your fancy content goes here... ]]></description>\r\n";
                $xml_content .= "<link>http://www.your-domain-name.co.uk/folder/yourPage.html</link>\r\n";
                $xml_content .= "<guid isPermaLink=\"true\">http://www.your-domain-name.co.uk/folder/yourPage.html</guid>\r\n";
                $xml_content .= "</item>\r\n";
                }
    $xml_content .= "</channel>\r\n";

    $xml_content .= "</rss>\r\n";

    // open xml feed file and truncate to zero length
    $xml_file = fopen("rss-feed.xml", "w");

    // write xml content to xml file
    fwrite($xml_file, $xml_content);

    // close xml file
    fclose($xml_file);

    header("location:rss-feed.xml");
```

My table contain 12 items but the result showing only one item. How is it?

Comment: Check the formatting of your code! ;-) Show us the sql query!

Comment: By the way, you can just echo the contents of the XML instead of writing it to disk, then redirecting to it. :)

Comment: it's not help.Till the result showing only one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They all have the same GUID and are thus marked as being multiple versions of the same item.

Comment: Good spot! Yes, @Testadmin, are you looking at the results in an RSS reader, rather than checking the XML output directly? Because the GUID in an RSS `<item>` is used by readers to tell the articles apart, so if the GUID is the same for all items, then they'll appear as a single item in some readers.

Comment: Is any other way to display all the Product in rss feeder?

Comment: No … but it really isn't difficult to make a globally unique id … err … unique.